# Does game center have to be included to get your app accepted?

Tags: ios, game-center, appstore-approval

I am developing a game and wondering if it is necessary to include game centre integration to get approved. I am having trouble figuring out how to include it, so if it isn't necessary, I may just submit it without, then add it later on. Is it necessary?

Comment: No, it's not required.

Comment: This question is off-topic because it is about App Store compliance, not a coding issue. Please see [Are developer-centric questions about application stores on topic for Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/175701)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need game center, however if you implement game center in a way apple frowns upon it will be rejected.

Comment: Thanks @Rick, good to know. For now I've taken it out because I can't find anything that helps me.. All the tutorials I've found are outdated. Do you know of any way to implement a leaderboard modal when a button is clicked on a view controller? Everything I've found is .xibs and ios4 and older.

Comment: Have you read the documentation? It looks like it might answer what you are trying to do. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/LeaderBoards/LeaderBoards.html